# ffmpeg get meta data in php or python

Tags: php, python, ffmpeg, mp3, id3-tag

I am trying to parse ffmpeg output in php to extract all meta data of a mp3 URL.

Is there any pre-written API or something in php or python?

We can use this command to generate a new mp3 file with specified tags:

```
ffmpeg -i inputfile -metadata title="Movie Title" -metadata year="2010" outputfile
```

But how can we extract them in an array or object?

Something like

```
$ffmpeg->setUrl(---- MP3 URL ---- );
$ffmpeg->getArtist();
$ffmpeg->getAlbum();
$ffmpeg->getYear();
```

Thanks,

Comment: Have a look at http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en. With the UNIX version you can export the data as XML, which should make it relatively easy to import with php or python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [this](http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/) is what you are looking for.

From the [API documentation](http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/doc/api/ffmpeg_movie.php):

```
$movie->getTitle()
$movie->getArtist()
$movie->getTrackNumber()
$movie->getYear()
$movie->getFrameHeight()
$movie->getFrameWidth()
$movie->getPixelFormat()
$movie->getBitRate()
```

and so on